# Angular component variable not passed to service by reference

Tags: angular, typescript, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Given the fact that objects and arrays in JavaScript are passed by reference (or to say their references are passed by value), if I pass an Angular component variable to service and make changes in service the changes should be reflected back in Angular component.

Code:

Component:

```
public onRowClicked(invoice) {
    this.rowService.onRowClicked(invoice, this.selectedrows);
  }
```

Service:

```
    public onRowClicked(invoice, selectedRows) {
     //make changes to selectedRows array
}
```

The value of `this.selectedRows` remains unchanged (while I expect it to change)

Am I getting at something wrong ?

Comment: how should selectedRows be changed, if you dont even change it? Maybe show more code

Comment: I haven't added code for that in my question but as my comment inside the method says I am changing the array

Comment: Can you log both instances

Comment: Yeah I totally understand that, I am just splicing few indexes based on few condition and may be I will have to do a `selectedRows = []`. Does that change the reference

Comment: Oh I know, you are trying to change it in service and hope the component has the change. Better you return the changed selectedRows in your service-method and do something like this.selectedRows = this.rowService.onRowClicked(...)

Comment: @CodeNashor, Yes that is correct, I am passing the component reference, changing it in service and expecting to reflect changes back in component.

Comment: The splice method returns a copy and does not modify the original array. I'm guessing that's the problem but it would help if you showed the code.

Comment: @CodeNashor I could have returned the value if it was a single value. Actually in my real code, there are multiple arrays that are passed and changed in service.

Comment: Then your code is not clean at all, if someone is looking at your code, he will say 'WTF WHERE GOT IT CHANGED??'. Edit your code to return the array .